# jquery - move div to top of view if its bigger than viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have div (like a layer) and have problem with visitors which have small resolution. Is there easy way to test if div height is bigger than page viewport and if yes, move div to top of viewport? Thanks

Comment: do you mean resize the div so its same as viewport?

Comment: no, resize can broke content. only move top of div to top of viewport. it's not important if all content is not visible, but close button on div top must be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
(function () {
    var viewport = window.innerWidth,
        el       = document.getElementById('myDiv'),
        widthDiv = el.style.width;

    if (widthDiv > viewport) {
    // Move the div higher
       el.style.zIndex = 999;
    }
}())
```